# Can't install laravel-elixir on npm install ERR ENOTDIR

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have an old project from a past developer, just trying to npm install and getting the following ENOTDIR error. It works if I remove the "laravel-elixir": "3.4.2" line, but that is the main one required to process the existing gulp file setup. I have tried npm clear cache and other general fixes without any luck as yet.

```
npm ERR! Linux 5.4.0-91-generic                                                                                            
npm ERR! argv "/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/bin/node" "/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/bin/npm" "install" "--no-bin-links"                                                                                                       
npm ERR! node v6.10.3                                                                                                      
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10                                                                                                     
npm ERR! path /home/vagrant/code/mahindra/public/wp-content/themes/mahindra/node_modules/.staging/@types/cors-202eb11f/package.json                                                                                                                   
npm ERR! code ENOTDIR                                                                                                      
npm ERR! errno -20                                                                                                         
npm ERR! syscall open                                                                                                      
npm ERR! ENOTDIR: not a directory, open '/home/vagrant/code/mahindra/public/wp-content/themes/mahindra/node_modules/.staging/@types/cors-202eb11f/package.json'
npm ERR!                                                                                                                   
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:                                                                   
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>                                                                           
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:                                                       
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/code/mahindra/public/wp-content/themes/mahindra/npm-debug.log
```

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "mahindra",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.5",
    "classlist": "^1.0.1",
    "cookies-js": "^1.2.2",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "google-map-react": "^0.4.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "match-media": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "0.13.3",
    "swiper": "4.5.0",
    "tipso": "1.0.8",
    "laravel-elixir": "3.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "lazyframe": "^1.1.3",
    "ouibounce": "0.0.11"
  }
}
```